# No decimal place in price card snapshots?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I'm working on a project where we are using Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update-1. When I try to add a price to a sellable-item, I have the problem, that I cannot save prices with decimal places.

When I try to use the American format (with a dot as a decimal separator), the dot will just be ignored. So if I enter "3.99" into the input, it will save "399".

[image: Input 3.99]

[image: Saved as 399]

When I try to use the German format (with a comma), it will give me an error.

[image: Price has incorrect decimal value]

Has anybody seen a problem like this in Sitecore XC 9?

Comment: It was a problem in 8.2.1 as well. You also could not enter any price > 999. Sitecore provided a fix for 8.2.1. You probably need to make sure you are logged in as a user editing "en" content, using "en" as your preferred language - and "en" being the default locale on the server. With all of the above, maybe. Just maybe.

Comment: Really. :-( OK, I might give it a try. But that doesn't sound like a real solution to me. 
But thank you for the heads up.

Comment: It's related to machine locale, try to change Region Format to English (United State). I've just tried to add price for snapshot like 3.99 and it works

Comment: Is this the only way to get this working? The customer owns the server and it is not hosted in the US. I will ask them, but I'm not sure if they are willing to change the Region Format.

Comment: Get the hotfix from Sitecore. But you need to go via their support portal for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to the Sitecore Support about this issues. This is a known bug in the Commerce Engine. The fix for this is the following:

1. Open Commerce Engine SDK project
2. Open "Startup.cs" file of Sitecore.Commerce.Engine project
3. Add the following code to the end of "Configure" method

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");`

4. Build project
5. Stop Commerce Engine and replace the "Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.exe" with one which you'be built.

We are using Sitecore Commerce 9 Update 1. I don't really know, if this is already fixed in Update 2. But if you are running Update 1 or the initial release, that should fix it.